# How to add row elements in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, firefoxdriver

I have written code like this

```
package testpk;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;        
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;        
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class Form {                


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {                                    

        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables        

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://beta-app.1bridge.in/#/auth/login"); 
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("bbbb",Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("123",Keys.ENTER);

        Thread.sleep(7000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-id='dashboard']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("#pcoded > div.pcoded-container.navbar-wrapper > div > div > div > div > div > div > app-default > div > app-modal-basic > div > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)"));

        int intColValue=0;
        int sum=0;
        String strColValue;

        //Loop through all the rows
        for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++)
        {
            //Get the columns in particular row
            List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

            //Here I am assuming values are 'String' type
            //Also, I have hard-corded the column number (which you should not do and use column name as input) 
            strColValue = cols.get(2).getText();
            //And convert those to 'Integer'
            intColValue = Integer.parseInt(strColValue);

            //Get the sum
            sum = sum+intColValue;
        }

        System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
    }

}
```

It showing error like this `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems`:

> rows cannot be resolved   rows cannot be resolved
>
> at testpk.Form.main(Form.java:38)

[image]

I want to add those row elements can anyone please guide me

Comment: Can anyone please suggust me

Comment: Apart from the issue you're facing, here: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("#pcoded > div.pcoded-container.navbar-wrapper > div > div > div > div > div > div > app-default > div > app-modal-basic > div > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)"));` you are trying to look up element using xPath locator but provide css locator.

Comment: java is telling you that it doesn't know what `rows` is because the code doesn't ever create or set a variable named `rows` that it can see.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in your code.

This will work for you if you want to sum today's value:-

```
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-id='dashboard']")).click();
      //this will count all <TR> in your current page.
      List<WebElement> element= driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
      //System.out.println(element.size());
      int integerValue;
      int sumValue=0;
      for(int i=1;i<=element.size()-1;i++)
      {
          //Here enter your Xpath value for the table.
          WebElement todaysValue= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='example']//tr["+i+"]/td[2]"));
          String tableValue=todaysValue.getText();
          integerValue=Integer.parseInt(tableValue);
          sumValue=sumValue+integerValue;         
      }
      System.out.println("Total Sum : "+sumValue);
```

Also avoid using **Thread.sleep** in your script this will slow down your script and it's a bad practice, try to use **Explicit wait** in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Add below line before 'for' loop.

```
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

This would allow us to get all rows in the table.